# azure: malformed storage account key: illegal base64 data at input byte0 terraform CD

Tags: terraform, backend, account

Terraform backend uses a deprecated version of terraform and warns that it is been deprecated, even if you pinned to lower version or higher version `=2.0.0` or `>=0.11` throws  malformed storage account key

> [DEPRECATED] `arm_tenant_id` has been replaced by `tenant_id`[0m

-backend-config=storage_account_name=testcmsaamsdn

-backend-config=container_name=terraform

-backend-config=key=terraform.tfstate

-backend-config=resource_group_name=rg-testconfig-AMSDN

-backend-config=arm_subscription_id=000-000-000-000-000

-backend-config=arm_tenant_id=***

-backend-config=arm_client_id=***

-backend-config=arm_client_secret=***

```
Failed to get existing workspaces: Error creating storage client for storage account "testcmsaamsdn": azure: malformed storage account key: illegal base64 data at input byte 0[0m
```

Backend config looks like

terraform {

backend "azurerm" {

storage_account_name = `"__terraformstorageaccount__"`

container_name       = "terraform"

key                  = "terraform.tfstate"

access_key           = `"__storagekey__"`

}

}

Answer (score -1):

I believe that copy-pasting the inline ps script could produce malformed key.. I rewrote the script and it resolved.

Comment: Hi Ashish, can you share the ps script ?

Comment: That is not the way to write answers. Please explain what clearly what solved issue.